# Chrome ignoring ajax request

Tags: ajax, google-chrome, jquery, marionette

I have a Marionette view that does an ajax request. Chrome is ignoring the request while the request works correctly under Firefox.

The network tab in Chrome's inspector does not show that the Ajax call is made to the server. If I put the ajax url into Chrome it returns valid JSON. The Chrome console shows no Javascript errors.

Please help.

```
define([
'views/base/composite_view',
'views/product_item_view',
'myapp',
'jquery-ui',
'models/products',
'hbs!template/product_search'
], function(CompositeView, ProductItemView, MyApp, $, Products, template) {
'use strict';

var ProductsView = CompositeView.extend({
    template: template,
    itemView: ProductItemView,
    className: 'products',
    container: '#product_search',
    itemViewContainer: 'tbody',
    animationDuration: 0,

    events: {
        "click #btnSearchProduct": "search",
        "keypress #productSearchTerm": "keypressed"
    },

    keypressed: function(event) {
        var code = event.which;

        if (code == 13) {
            event.preventDefault();
            this.search();
        }
    },

    search: function() {
        var searchTerm = this.$('#productSearchTerm').val().trim();
        var productsView = this;
        var url = MyApp.options.baseUrl+'/jdeproductsearch?searchTerm='+searchTerm;

        $.getJSON(url, function(productData) {
            productsView.collection = new Products(productData);
            productsView.render();
        });
    },

    onRender: function() {
        var productsView = this;

        this.$('#productResultsTable tr').draggable({
            helper: 'clone',
            revert: 'invalid',
            start: function (event, ui) {
                $(this).css('opacity', '.5');
            },
            stop: function (event, ui) {
                $(this).css('opacity', '1');
            }
        })
        .css('cursor', 'pointer');
        }
    });
    return ProductsView;
});
```

Comment: Have you confirmed that the code that does the ajax request is even being reached?

Comment: Yes it is. I've put an alert above that line and it displays output

Comment: Next step, compare `url` to `window.location`, is the protocol, sub-domain, domain, or port different?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After restarting Chrome the problem seemed to go away.